# How we can show that Taylor series of a real-valued function of a complex vector variable is real-valued?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, vector-analysis

How Can I show that the imaginary part of the derivative (and thus the first-order Taylor series) of this function is zero?

${\lvert \boldsymbol{v}^H\boldsymbol{a}+b \rvert}^{2}$

where $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{a}$ are two $N*1$ vectors and $b$ is a scalar.also $\boldsymbol{v}$ is the variable.

I know that:
${\lvert \boldsymbol{v}^H\boldsymbol{a}+b \rvert}^{2}=(\boldsymbol{v}^H\boldsymbol{a}+b)*(\boldsymbol{v}^H\boldsymbol{a}+b)^H=
\boldsymbol{v}^H\boldsymbol{a}\boldsymbol{a}^H\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{v}^Hb^H\boldsymbol{a}+b\boldsymbol{a}^H\boldsymbol{v}+\lvert b \rvert^2$

and thus the derivative w.r.t. $\boldsymbol{v}$ is (by supposing that $\boldsymbol{v}$ would real):

$2\boldsymbol{a}\boldsymbol{a}^H\boldsymbol{v}+2*b^H\boldsymbol{a}$

but...

Comment: Derivative with respect to what?

Comment: @S.H.W with respect to $\boldsymbol{v}$

Comment: You cannot have a Taylor series of a real valued non constant function of a complex variable.

Comment: Conjugation is not complex differentiable. You have $v^H$ in your expression, how are you going to get the derivative with respect to $v$? Take the simplest example: $a=1,\;b=0,\;N=1.$ You would have to find the derivative of $z\overline{z}$ with respect to $z$, which does not exist, see [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)

Comment: I think this question is useful: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51248/derivative-with-respect-to-complex-conjugate

Comment: @copper.hat why? then how can I approximate such functions?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @copper.hat I need to approximate this function with an affine estimator.